# What's a word for a blamer who blames others for their own guilt?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What's a word to describe a person that accuses others of feeling how they feel because they are ashamed of that feeling within themselves?

eg.

> Cathy is a classic [noun] - she would loudly criticise Sue for arriving to the office late, though Cathy had also been known to arrive late on more than one occasion.
>
> Jim described me as irresponsible for taking the weekend off away from my family, but I think he was [adjective] here, feeling guilty himself for working long hours during the week and not seeing his family.

Comment: To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  (See http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info for details of single-word-request question requirements.)

Comment: Hi Casey - I think a lot of your questions could be improved with an example. I'll edit this one to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

**Projection** might be what you are referring to.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_projection:

> Psychological projection is a theory in psychology in which humans
>   defend themselves against unpleasant impulses by denying their
>   existence in themselves, while attributing them to others. For
>   example, a person who is rude may constantly accuse other people of
>   being rude.
>
> According to some research, the projection of one's negative qualities
>   onto others is a common process in everyday life.

In short, the person would be said to be projecting.

Answer (score 0):

**[scapegoater:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scapegoater)** one that makes a [scapegoat](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scapegoat) of something or somebody

Answer (score -1):

*Narcissist*? They tend to place blame on others rather than accepting that something is their fault.

Comment: Politician...:)  :) :)